# MS Word VSTO Add-In - determining the source of open request

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I have an MS Word VSTO addin that sets 2 Document.Variables for certain documents processed by the addin.

Since the variables are saved with the document, if a user opens the document, say from Windows explorer or from an email, the variables persist -- and this is what I want.

However, I want to distinguish documents that are opened from "within" the add in from documents that are opened from an external application (Explorer or Outlook email) and then treat each slightly differently. I'd like to make this determination in the DocumentOpen event of the Add in.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do this?  I don't think I can add a NEW variable before the document is opened (which would be ideal) but perhaps someone has another idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Add a third variable called e.g. OpenedWithinMyAddim

Comment: @simon the problem with this that, then, the variable will be tracked with each save of the document (or I'd have to remove it before closing, which would create another save event which I don't want).  Further, I don't think I can ACT on the document UNTIL it is open so I couldn't affect this variable in the DocumentOpen event.